# Error: Cannot access private property FileType symfony3

Tags: php, symfony

Currently, I would like to send files from any extension to my database. But, actually, when I print the file's value return by the form: I got this :

> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object ( [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => IMPOTS 2016.pdf [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => application/pdf [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 1621929 [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0 [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp/phpV9G6Sg [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpV9G6Sg )

But I want only the name of the file -> IMPOTS 2016.pdf
And when I try to get juste the name, symfony return :

```
Error: Cannot access private property Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::$originalName
```

Ok this is my fonction who work with data :

```
public function AddFile($valeursForm)
{  
    $File = new Transfert;
    $File->setDESTINATAIRE($valeursForm['DESTINATAIRE']->Id);
    $File->setEMAIL($valeursForm['EMAIL']);
    $File->setOF($valeursForm['OF']);
    $File->setDEVIS($valeursForm['DEVIS']);
    $File->setAFFAIRE($valeursForm['AFFAIRE']);
    $File->setLOGICIEL($valeursForm['LOGICIEL']);
    $File->setINFORMATION($valeursForm['INFORMATION']);
    $File->setLIVRAISON($valeursForm['LOGICIEL']);
    $file = $valeursForm['NOM_FILE'];
    print_r($file);
    $filename = $file->originalName;
    $path = $this->ListeSocieteId($valeursForm['ID_SOCIETE']);
    $path = $this->Core_Caracteres->RemplacementCaracteresSpeciaux($path->NOM);
    $path = strtoupper($path);
    $path = str_replace(" ", "_", $path);
    $path = ('sermati/ftp/'.$path."/POUR_".$path);
    $file->move(
            $path,
            $filename);
    $File->setNOMFILE($filename);
    print_r($filename);
    $this->Core_ConnexionsBDD->Mise_a_jour_BDD('extranet',array($File));
    //On créé le message d'alerte
    $messageSucces = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Le fichier a bien été ajoutée.';
    $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('success',$messageSucces);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [getClientOriginalName](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_getClientOriginalName) instead.

```
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
```